# Resampling and add threshold information in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have my pandas data frame in 1 min frequency, I want to do the re-sampling based on the threshold data (there are multiple thresholds in a numpy array)

Here is example of my dataset:

```
2018-01-01 00:01:00    0.867609
2018-01-01 00:02:00    0.544493
2018-01-01 00:03:00    0.958497
2018-01-01 00:04:00    0.371790
2018-01-01 00:05:00    0.470320
2018-01-01 00:06:00    0.757448
2018-01-01 00:07:00    0.198261
2018-01-01 00:08:00    0.666350
2018-01-01 00:09:00    0.392574
2018-01-01 00:10:00    0.627608
2018-01-01 00:11:00    0.414380
2018-01-01 00:12:00    0.120925
2018-01-01 00:13:00    0.559495
2018-01-01 00:14:00    0.260619
2018-01-01 00:15:00    0.982731
2018-01-01 00:16:00    0.996133
2018-01-01 00:17:00    0.410816
2018-01-01 00:18:00    0.366457
2018-01-01 00:19:00    0.927745
2018-01-01 00:20:00    0.626804
2018-01-01 00:21:00    0.223193
2018-01-01 00:22:00    0.007136
2018-01-01 00:23:00    0.245006
2018-01-01 00:24:00    0.491245
2018-01-01 00:25:00    0.215716
2018-01-01 00:26:00    0.932378
2018-01-01 00:27:00    0.366263
2018-01-01 00:28:00    0.522177
2018-01-01 00:29:00    0.614966
2018-01-01 00:30:00    0.670983

threshold=np.array([0.5,0.8,0.9])
```

What I want is to extract the data where it crosses the threshold values and if doesn't cross the threshold value just resample data at 30 min

Sample ans :

```
                                   Threshold
2018-01-01 00:01:00    0.867609        0.8
2018-01-01 00:02:00    0.544493        0.5
2018-01-01 00:03:00    0.958497        0.9
2018-01-01 00:05:00    0.421055        NA
2018-01-01 00:06:00    0.757448        0.5
2018-01-01 00:07:00    0.198261        NA
2018-01-01 00:08:00    0.666350        0.5
2018-01-01 00:09:00    0.392574        NA
2018-01-01 00:10:00    0.627608        0.5
2018-01-01 00:12:00    0.414380        NA
2018-01-01 00:13:00    0.559495        0.5
2018-01-01 00:14:00    0.260619        NA
2018-01-01 00:15:00    0.982731        0.9
2018-01-01 00:16:00    0.996133        0.9
2018-01-01 00:18:00    0.388636        NA
2018-01-01 00:19:00    0.927745        0.9
2018-01-01 00:20:00    0.626804        0.5
2018-01-01 00:25:00    0.215716        NA
2018-01-01 00:26:00    0.932378        0.9
2018-01-01 00:27:00    0.366263        NA
2018-01-01 00:28:00    0.522177        0.5
2018-01-01 00:29:00    0.614966        0.5
2018-01-01 00:30:00    0.670983        0.5
```

I got the solution for resampling from @Scott Boston,

```
df = df.set_index(0)

g = df[1].lt(-22).mul(1).diff().bfill().ne(0).cumsum()

df.groupby(g).apply(lambda x: x.resample('1T', kind='period').mean().reset_index()
                           if (x.iloc[0] < -22).any() else 
                              x.resample('30T', kind='period').mean().reset_index())\
   .reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: @ScottBoston I have reworded my question, hope its clear now.

Comment: Yes, that is much better.  Thank you for simplifying and clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

Use `pd.cut`:

```
threshold=np.array([0.5,0.8,0.9]).tolist()
pd.cut(df[1],bins=threshold+[np.inf],labels=threshold)
```

Output:

```
0     0.8
1     0.5
2     0.9
3     NaN
4     NaN
5     0.5
6     NaN
7     0.5
8     NaN
9     0.5
10    NaN
11    NaN
12    0.5
13    NaN
14    0.9
15    0.9
16    NaN
17    NaN
18    0.9
19    0.5
20    NaN
21    NaN
22    NaN
23    NaN
24    NaN
25    0.9
26    NaN
27    0.5
28    0.5
29    0.5
Name: 1, dtype: category
Categories (3, float64): [0.5 < 0.8 < 0.9]
```

Now, let's add this to the datafame and filter out all consecutive NaNs.

```
df['Threshold'] = pd.cut(df[1],bins=threshold+[np.inf],labels=threshold)
mask = ~(df.Threshold.isnull() & (df.Threshold.isnull() == df.Threshold.isnull().shift(1)))
df[mask]
```

Output:

```
                      0         1 Threshold
0   2018-01-01 00:01:00  0.867609       0.8
1   2018-01-01 00:02:00  0.544493       0.5
2   2018-01-01 00:03:00  0.958497       0.9
3   2018-01-01 00:04:00  0.371790       NaN
5   2018-01-01 00:06:00  0.757448       0.5
6   2018-01-01 00:07:00  0.198261       NaN
7   2018-01-01 00:08:00  0.666350       0.5
8   2018-01-01 00:09:00  0.392574       NaN
9   2018-01-01 00:10:00  0.627608       0.5
10  2018-01-01 00:11:00  0.414380       NaN
12  2018-01-01 00:13:00  0.559495       0.5
13  2018-01-01 00:14:00  0.260619       NaN
14  2018-01-01 00:15:00  0.982731       0.9
15  2018-01-01 00:16:00  0.996133       0.9
16  2018-01-01 00:17:00  0.410816       NaN
18  2018-01-01 00:19:00  0.927745       0.9
19  2018-01-01 00:20:00  0.626804       0.5
20  2018-01-01 00:21:00  0.223193       NaN
25  2018-01-01 00:26:00  0.932378       0.9
26  2018-01-01 00:27:00  0.366263       NaN
27  2018-01-01 00:28:00  0.522177       0.5
28  2018-01-01 00:29:00  0.614966       0.5
29  2018-01-01 00:30:00  0.670983       0.5
```